# Jquery new github plugin system

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, github

I have followed all the steps at the plugins.jquery.com repo on github (https://github.com/jquery/plugins.jquery.com/) to be ready to add my plugin to the new system, I have a plugin called Tweetslider in the old repository, but I am confused.

I have set up the local jquery sites using /etc/hosts to route it to my ip, and set up all the node.js functionality. I assumed that publishing a plugin would be done via the wp-admin of the local site, but it seems this is not the case.

The more I read, the more it seems that I simply add a jquery.json manifest file in the root of my repository,  add the post-receive-hook in github to the plugins site receiving url, and post a new tag with the version number, which will then be picked up by jquery plugins site and added. If this is the case, why did I bother with the web-base-template etc and all the setting up of the local plugins db etc?

My repository for tweetslider is here https://github.com/LiamBailey/TweetSlider

If I follow the steps above would my plugin be added or re-added provided the manifest was valid, or am I missing something?

For example at the end of the readme on the jquery repo linked at top of post it gives as the final instruction:

Running the site

node scripts/manager.js

But when I run this it does absolutely nothing. I have checked the sysmonitor and a node applet is in there, but I can't see anything visually happening. I have looked at the code but I don't get that either. All the Wordpress stuff is perfect, I have the local jQUery and I can login. I hope someone else has looked at all this and made a better understanding of it than I, as I think I will go crazy soon.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, this drove me crazy too. The key thing is that github can not know about your /etc/hosts and can not know about your local server.

- The web-base-template and wordpress stuff is so you can view the site.
- The node server receives the post-receive-hook and then adds the info directly into wordpress.
- Changing /etc/hosts sets up a domain name so you can view the local wordpress site however no one else can see this, in particular github.

Some potential workarounds:

- Setup a local git server which has a post-receive-hook to your local machine.  This way all the necessary hostname routing is handled with your local /etc/hosts.
- Use some sort of dynamic DNS or related system to have a public hostname that directs to your localy running server and have github hook into that.
- Proxy the post-receive-hook through your own personal public server to your local server.

You could also ask the people on the jquery forums if they have any more insight into configuring a local environment.

Answer (score 1):

**Update 2013-01-17**

The jQuery Plugins Registry is finally up! http://plugins.jquery.com

The instructions are pretty straigtforward now, http://plugins.jquery.com/docs/publish/

And the specifications for the manifest are also clearly detailed at http://plugins.jquery.com/docs/package-manifest/

---

> If I follow the steps above would my plugin be added or re-added provided the manifest was valid, or am I missing something?

According to the [README.md](https://github.com/jquery/plugins.jquery.com/blob/master/README.md), it warns that it is not working yet. This system is under (slow) development.

> Simply add a post-receive hook to your repository with our web hook
>   url, http://plugins.jquery.com/_update. **Warning: This is not yet
>   functional!**

Also I noticed the [last commit](https://github.com/jquery/plugins.jquery.com/commit/4f5f611d247db6b3df11a2a5bda0957d08f11d6f#diff-0) made a month ago was about updating said post-receive hook to `http://plugins.jquery.com/postreceive-hook` in their docs on publishing at https://github.com/jquery/plugins.jquery.com/blob/4f5f611d247db6b3df11a2a5bda0957d08f11d6f/site-content/page/docs/publish.html

Things like that kind of add to the confusion but you could try asking and/or looking in https://github.com/jquery/plugins.jquery.com/issues

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that it is not yet functional, that is why I asked "would" my plugin be added, not will. Thanks for the link to the updated docs, but apart from that you aren't telling me anything I didn't already know, and for that reason I can't accept your answer.

Comment: That's fine, and I wasn't expecting you to accept it as an answer. I just couldn't fit it all nicely in a comment.

Comment: I didn't mean any offence, just wanted to give an explanation as to why I wasn't accepting. Thanks again for the answer, it did indirectly help, in that reading the revised docs made me pretty sure that all I need do is write a jquery.json manifest and add a post update hook.